# run-jetty-run won't display my jsp

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jetty, runjettyrun

Im using run-jetty-run 9 to test my web application project in eclipse.
Whenever I'm trying to access a JSP on this local deployment created with run-jetty-run, I'm getting this error:

> PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just
>   JRE) is required
>
> Caused by:
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in
>   invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

As far as I know this could be caused by an unused line in the start.ini. (this -DORG ... thingy)
How can I configure run-jetty-run to run jsp? 
Is there some kind of a start.ini in the depths of my eclipse folder?
Since I want to use servlets api 3.0 I can't use below jetty 9.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. You need to have a full JDK and run run-jetty-run using that JDK.

Download the most recent JDK from http://java.sun.com, install it, then set JAVA_HOME to point to your JDK. Probably set PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH additionally. Make sure that these settings are set for run-jetty-run and you should have that error fixed.

As a sidenote Jetty 8 supports Servlet 3.0 as well. But I'd recommend you to stay with Jetty 9.